# KVM - Can't ping from physical network to virtual gateway

Tags: networking, routing, kvm-virtualization

Consider the following diagram:

[image: diagram]

This is the SERVER01 NIC's configuration:

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:ae:52:c0:e6:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.251/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d6ae:52ff:fec0:e6c5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b1:de:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This server has the following routes:

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eno1 onlink 
10.0.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.251 
192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

And the virtual network has the following XML:

```
<network connections='2'>
  <name>pxb-vn</name>
  <uuid>2445d9f0-e67c-4654-99ce-297642280b04</uuid>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='virbr1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:b1:de:03'/>
  <domain name='pxb-vn'/>
  <ip address='192.168.100.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I want to server one service per each virtual server. For now it worked adding the following route to physical linux computers:

```
ip r add 192.168.100.0/24 via 10.0.1.251 dev eth0
```

And this route to virtual servers:

```
ip r add 10.0.1.0/24 via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
```

But my company's network is a mix of Windows, Mac OS and Linux computers and I think it's not practical to configure each physical computer with this rule. As you can see, I have set a routed virtual network and I think it should be possible to ping to 192.168.100.1 from the 10.0.1.0/24 network but it's not working. I'm a KVM and networking newbie and I think I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's not practical to configure each physical computer with this rule.

There are a bunch of alternatives to doing that, but for a small network they're pretty much all significantly more complicated than just setting up a static route everywhere.

The only one that might be simpler is to configure the default gateway for those physical machines to itself hold the route for the VM network.  This will result in some degree of inefficiency, as the packets travel from the physical machine, through the router, to the VM server, and onto the VM, rather than directly from the physical machine to the VM server, but the additional traffic and latency is unlikely to be noticeable in a small network.

Comment: setuo a nat might be easier

Comment: NAT has nothing to do with this problem.